# Oozie could not be started -usergroupiformation error

Tags: oozie

**sudo ./bin/oozied.sh run**

ERROR: Oozie could not be started

REASON: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)V

Comment: You have conflicts in jars.

Comment: which jar and what conflict. Can you please explain. Iam breaking my head with this.

Comment: i guess hadoop-common.

Comment: thanks.  I solved the problem.Its working